# Differential equation with $x$-axis as horizontal asymptote

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Among all the functions $y = f (x)$, which satisfy the differential equation:

$$y'(x) = -e^{x-y}$$

Determine the function which admits the $x$-axis as horizontal asymptote.

The reference solution of my book is:

$$y = \ln \Big(\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}\Big)$$

Thank you very much for considering my request.

Comment: Could the RHS of your ODE be $-e^{y-x}$ instead? Otherwise I don't see how their answer works.

Comment: In fact the general solution of your DE is
$$ y = \ln(A - e^x) $$
and thus no solutions have horizontal asymptotes: they all blow up as $x \to \ln(A)-$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake in the wording of your problem. The equation is not $y'(x) = -e^{x-y}$, but is  $y'(x) = -e^{y-x}$

First, you have to find the general solution $y = \ln \Big(\frac{e^x}{Ce^x-1}\Big)$, then detemine $C$ so that $y=0$ for $x$ tending to infinity.